# If then Else Loop - Doesn't delete all items

Tags: loops, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing script that creates and then deletes Template. If the script fails (before the template is deleted), I need a way to delete the Template the next time the Script runs.

I've created a if then else loop, but it won't delete the 2nd Template. What am I doing wrong? Many Thanks :)

```
            while (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Automation_TemplateXX')]")).size() !=0){

        // Clicks on Edit Template Button
        WebElement SearchTPF = this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Automation_TemplateXX')]//following-sibling::div")));
        SearchTPF.click();  
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-area-wrapper']")));

        // Click Delete Button
        WebElement deleteTP = this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Delete Template')]")));
        deleteTP.click();

        // Alert Pop Up > Confirm Deletion
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert confirmPop = driver.switchTo().alert();
        confirmPop.accept();
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='tabPage_thread_id_1002523']//ul[contains(@class, 'list-unstyled') and contains(@class, 'thread-messages') and contains(@class, 'to-print')]")));
        log.info("Template was Deleted Successfully, Current url " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }
```

Comment: `if else` is not a loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a complete noob. How should I do a loop?

Comment: I'm using a while loop now, but I'm not sure how to get it to stop.